# Объединить функции вызывающиеся по .resize() и .scroll()

Tags: jquery

Имеется код функции работающий с шириной и уровнем прокрутки $(window). Вызывать эту функцию необходимо либо в момент прокрутки страницы, либо в момент изменения размеров окна.

Подскажите, поалуйста, как объединить два этих события?

Другим словами нужно объединить:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    /* код функции */
});

$(window).resize(function(){
    /* тот же код функции */
});
```

**UPD: Решение**

[**Правильно:**](#answer-container-147785)

```
var func = function(e){ /* resize and scroll logic */};
$(window).scroll(func).resize(func);
```

[**Не правильно:**](#comment-147787)

```
$(window).scroll(function() { func() });
$(window).resize(function() { func() });
```

Comment: В голвоу так же приходит вариант прописать функцию отдельно и в случаях scroll и resize вызывать ее по ее идентификатору.

Comment: Нет, все верно, спасибо :). Достаточно элегантно! :) Я дошел еще до такого варианта: 

`$(window).scroll(function() {
 func()
});`

`$(window).resize(function() {
 func()
});`

Comment: @Cypher, отметьте ответ @Spectre как правильный, а свой оставьте, в качестве примера того, как делать не надо ))

Comment: Вы про сам код или про форматирования комментария? :)

P.S. наконец нашел кнопочку преобразования комментария в ответ. В следующий раз сам справлюсь :). Спасибо )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

не пойму что в этом сложного:

```
var func = function(e){ /* resize and scroll logic */};

$(window).scroll(func).resize(func);
```

или проблема глубже?